# How to add custom order list in excel over the allowed limit?

Tags: excel, sorting

How to add custom order list over the allowed limit in excel sort? I'm on office 2010 32 - bit.

I get this message, "the maximum length for a custom list has been exceeded. Only the first 255 characters will be saved."

Comment: Are you using a validation list or are you using a combo box on a form?

Comment: No validation list, just trying to sort a list with  +5k values with another list with the same values but different order.

Comment: as you are on 2010 you will need to build a helper column which returns the index of the value in the other list - then sort by this helper column

Comment: Hey, can i ask, how i can go around doing that, step by step?